# How to destroy objects referenced to the array without removing them from array in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have recently started creating a game, but when I try to destroy objects on a scene they also remove from the list. Here is the code:

```
        List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();
        int x = 650;
        // Here I try to destroy objects
        foreach(Transform obj in transform) {
            Destroy(obj.gameObject);
        }
        // Here I instantiate all objects from the array
        for(int i = 0;i < objects.Count;i++) {
            if(objects.Count == 3) {
                GameObject prefab_copy = (GameObject)Instantiate(objects[i], new Vector2(x, 1150), Quaternion.identity );
                prefab_copy.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
                prefab_copy.transform.SetParent(parentobj.transform);
                x = x + 100;
            }
        }
        cleanItemList = true;
```

Comment: No it won't ... Except there is more code for removing the items from the list you didn't show us ... They will be `null` afterwards though so what is the use of keeping the list items?

Comment: With the provided code your objects list will always be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping null values in a list and then trying to instantiate from it is dangerous , please remove from list as soon as you destroy the game-object , You cannot keep a reference to a deleted gameobject in play mode.

My Advice is to make a helper method that can find new references in the scene and add them to the list whenever you want or make a prefab of the gameobject you want and populate the list as per requirement and delete as needed.As far as I can understand the problem you need to learn OBJECT POOLING.It will help you reuse the same objects and improve performance.